# Security concerns for connecting rancher nodes with public id

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Assume that when you create nodes in rancher you don't fill private IP fields, so nodes will connect through public ip, does it have any security issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of Rancher you are using. In 1.6, the cross-host communication happens over IPSec tunnels, whereas in 2.x, depending on the network plugin, it could be mostly VXLAN.

I wouldn't use VXLAN overlay over the internet. IPSec is designed for secure communications.

Also, I would use some form of protection using features like Security Groups to shut down the use of other ports.

If you really don't have a use case to use public IP addresses, you should override the defaults to use private IP addresses.

Comment: I'm on rancher 2 and there is no private network between hosts (so I think there might be some security measures about opening these ports to the public) - I'll read more about IPsec.